# How do I minimize this constrained function?

Tags: numerics, mathematical-optimization

I have given a set of complex variables $A_{a,s,j,n}$, real valued parameters $C_1,C_2,C_3$ and $C_4$ and summation limits $N_1,N_2$.

I want to minimize the following function:
$$F(\{A_{a,s,j,n}\}) = \sum_{n=0}^{N_1}\sum_{j=0}^{N_2}\sum_{s=0}^1 \Bigg[ -2C_1 \textrm{Re}\Big( A_{0,s,j,n}^* A_{1,s,j,n}\Big) 
-2C_2 \textrm{Re}\Big( A_{0,s,(j+1),n}^* A_{1,s,j,n}\Big) 
+ \frac{1}{2} (1+s\cdot(-1)^{(j-1)}) C_3 \sum_{a=0}^1  |A_{a,s,j,n}|^2 \Bigg]
\\+ C_4 \sum_{j=0}^{N_2}\sum_{a=0}^1  \Big( \sum_{n=0}^{N_1} |A_{a,0,j,n}|^2\Big) \cdot \Big( \sum_{n=0}^{N_1} |A_{a,1,j,n}|^2\Big)$$

with the following constraint:
$$\delta_{n,m} = \sum_{j=0}^{N_2}\sum_{s=0}^1  \sum_{a=0}^1 A_{a,s,j,n}^* A_{a,s,j,m} $$
The symbol $\delta_{n,m}$ is the Kronkecker delta (=1 if both indices are the same, 0 in all other cases).

I now want to find the Minimum of $F$, given a set of parameters $C_i$. I don't really care much about the value $F$ takes at the minimum but I need the values of the complex variables $A_{a,s,j,n}$ at which the minimum occurs.

How to I implement this in mathematica?

### EDIT:

What I tried is the following:
First I defined the parameters:

```
c1 = 1;
c2 = 1;
c3= 1;
c4=1;
u = 1;
n1 = 2;
n2 = 2;
```

and then wrote down the function $F$ (called $h$ here)

```
h = Sum[-2*c1*Re[Conjugate[a[0][s][j][n]] * a[1][s][j][n] ] - 
     2*c2*Re[Conjugate[a[0][s][j + 1][n]]*a[1][s][j][n] ] + 
     0.5*(1 + s*(-1)^(j - 1))*c3*
      Sum[Abs[a[\[Alpha]][s][j][n] ]^2, {\[Alpha], 0, 1}], {s, 0, 
     1}, {j, 0, n2 - 1}, {n, 0, n1 - 1}] + 
   c4*Sum[(Sum[Abs[a[\[Alpha]][0][j][n]]^2, {n, 0, n1 - 1}])*(Sum[
        Abs[a[\[Alpha]][1][j][n]]^2, {n, 0, n1 - 1}]), {j, 0, 
      n2 - 1}, {\[Alpha], 0, 1}];
```

I defined a single constraint as

```
con[n_, m_] := 
 KroneckerDelta[n, m] == 
  Sum[Conjugate[a[\[Alpha]][s][j][n]]*a[\[Alpha]][s][j][m], {\[Alpha],
     0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {j, 0, n2 - 1}]
```

so that the constraints for all $n,m$ are given by

```
allCon = Table[con[i, j], {i, 0, n1 - 1}, {j, 0, n1 - 1}];
```

The variables are given by

```
vars = Table[a[\[Alpha]][s][j][n], {\[Alpha], 0, 1}, {s, 0, 1}, {j, 0, 
    n2 - 1}, {n, 0, n1 - 1}] // Flatten
```

I then tried to minimize this:

```
NMinimize[{h, allCon}, vars]
```

However, this failed with error "not a number". How do I fix this?

Comment: You can start by checking `Minimize`, `NMinimize` or `FindMinimum` in the documentation.

Comment: I looked at this functions, thanks! What I am interested in is an efficient implementation, where I can change the summation limit $N_1$ and $N_2$ easily whithout having to retype the whole equation. Also I don't know how to implement the kronecker delta efficiently.

Comment: For Kronecker delta, you can check `KroneckerDelta`. For the rest, have you tried defining a function of $N_1$ and $N_2$? What have you tried?

Comment: Why don't you try a simpler example first? Building the expression piece-by-piece is a useful tool.

Comment: @anderstood I tried to write down, what I did up to now. Please have a look at my edit

Comment: You forgot `nMol` and `nEl`.

Comment: @anderstood Sorry, just a typo. Should have been `n1` and `n2`. This was not the problem in the code

Comment: What about `c4`?

Comment: @anderstood also set to 1, I will edit this.

Comment: I'm not sure where the error comes from, so if I were you I would follow `march`'s advice and simplify a lot, to add complexity little by little (as in any debugging process).

Comment: @anderstood I found the problem: I use the index j+1 at one point, but the variable was not defined for this value. How can I make sure that a[j+1]=a[0] if j is the maximum value `n2`?

Comment: @Merlin1896 You can always define all `a[j]=0` for $j\leq n_2+1$, but probably this is the symptom of something that you have not well implemented/understood.